# Extending space in C drive using the unallocated space using Gparted on Windows XP

Tags: partitioning

The unallocated space(10 GB) is currently right after the D:drive from which it was freed.How do i now move it to C drive to increase its capacity?

I have used Gparted Live CD to do the job.Now the the D drive(which i shrank)is sandwiched between C drive and the unallocated space.

Comment: where is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup, boot from a LiveCD with GParted and partition the drive as you want it.

Comment: Now the unallocated space sits right after C partion,but i am unable to extend it.Am i missing something?